# Mobile background image moves

Tags: html, css, mobile

My mobile background-image is moving. In every page it has an different position.

My css code:

```
body {

    background-image: url('/IMG/city.jpg') center center cover no-repeat fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Also tried this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    /* The file size of this background image is 93% smaller
       to improve page load speed on mobile internet connections */
    background-image: url(/IMG/mobile_background.bmp);
  }
}
```

Also I put this in my HTML files

```
<head>
        <title>My name/title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/IMG/favicon.ico"/>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/mobile.css" />
        <!-- Viewport is voor mobile devices --> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 

    </head>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: it will be great, if you share screenshots or create jsfiddle with actual code. so that we can help you in better way.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I have this problem only in the mobile version of my page. Is that possible to make on jsfiddle?